# scilab plotting factorial; first trying to correct the equation?

Tags: plot, equation, factorial, scilab

I'm trying to execute this equation in scilab; however, I'm getting error: 59 of function %s_pow called ... even though I define x.

```
n=0:1:3;
x=[0:0.1:2];
z = factorial(3); w = factorial(n);u = factorial(3-n);
y = z /(w.*u);
t = y.*x^n*(1-x)^(3-n)
```

(at this point I haven't added in the plot command, although I would assume it's plot(t)?)

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 1):

The power `x^n` and `(1-x)^(3-n)` on the last line both cause the problem, because `x` and `n` are matrices and they are not the same size.

As mentioned in the [documentation](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.3.3/en_US/power.html) the power operation can only be performed between:

> - (**A:square**)^(**b:scalar**) If A is a square matrix and b is a scalar then A^b is the matrix A to the power b.
> - (**A:matrix**).^(**b:scalar**) If b is a scalar and A a matrix then A.^b is
>     the matrix formed by the element of A to the power b (elementwise
>     power). If A is a vector and b is a scalar then A^b and A.^b performs
>     the same operation (i.e elementwise power).
> - (**A:scalar**).^(**b:matrix**)  If A is a scalar and b is a matrix (or
>     vector) A^b and A.^b are the matrices (or vectors) formed by
>     a^(b(i,j)).
> - (**A:matrix**).^(**b:matrix**) If A and b are vectors (matrices) of **the same
>     size** A.^b is the A(i)^b(i) vector (A(i,j)^b(i,j) matrix).